# Redirect entire VHost to HTTPS on same domain

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I have a vhost that accepts all domains and subdomains from 4 top domain names, e.g. `example.com`, `example.org`, `three.example.co.uk` etc.

I want the entire VHost to redirect to the exact same URL as requested, but HTTPS.

I know of this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.all *.other *.domains
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

but that won't work for subdomains, because explicit target URL.

It's so easy in nginx:

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

so I thought Apache would have a thing for that, and it sort-of does, but this doesn't work (no Apache error, just broken redirect):

```
Redirect permanent / https://%{HTTP_HOST}/
```

Is there any way to use a domain/host variable? Bonus points for not using `RewriteRule`!

Comment: What do you have against `RewriteRule` ?

Comment: @krisFR Nothing, but it should be unnecessary. What do you have against bonus points. You know how **with** `RewriteRule`?

Comment: Don't take it bad, it was just a friendly question...you could have reason like "performance" or so...By the way i have nothing against bonus points but how could you provide this ? The best you can do would be an upvote and an accepted answer : nothing bonus here. I admit i know with `RewriteRule` as i have done this kind of setup many times. Also Googling gives a lot of samples, you've found one :) Glad it works for you now. have a nice day :)

Comment: @krisFR Haha the bonus points were more of a mental thing. You have plenty of real points =) I don't know about perf, but it can't be all that bad. I only googled for 'without mod_rewrite' and couldn't find it. Still would be cool

Comment: I only know the `mod_rewrite` method. If this could be achieved using only `redirect` i would be glad to learn about it also, just like you !! :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer in [Apache SSL New Domain Redirect](https://serverfault.com/questions/83658/apache-ssl-new-domain-redirect?rq=1) is good enough. (Didn't see that one while typing question.)

Solution:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com etc
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Using `%{HTTP_HOST}` in target URL seems to work fine with Apache 2.4.

Any method without rewriting, like nginx does? Or not worth it?